# How to duplicate an existing order (core, php) with Prestashop 1.6.x in FrontPage from client Account - My Orders?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

if i use a function in classes\duplicateOrder, found on a previous answer, everytime i refresh the page order-history, all orders from my account->orders are duplicated
 the function seems to be ok, so where is the problem?

```
public function duplicateOrder($id_order)
{
    $order = new Order($id_order);

    $duplicatedOrder = $order->duplicateObject();

    $orderDetailList = $order->getOrderDetailList();
    foreach ($orderDetailList as $detail) {
        $orderDetail = new orderDetail($detail['id_order_detail']);
        $duplicatedOrderDetail = $orderDetail->duplicateObject();
        $duplicatedOrderDetail->id_order = $duplicatedOrder->id;
        $duplicatedOrderDetail->save();
    }

    $orderHistoryList = $order->getHistory(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
    foreach ($orderHistoryList as $history) {
        $orderHistory = new OrderHistory($history['id_order']);
        $duplicatedOrderHistory = $orderHistory->duplicateObject();
        $duplicatedOrderHistory->id_order = $duplicatedOrder->id;
        //$duplicatedOrderHistory->save();
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your call? I think you call it in a foreach that lists the commands.

Regards

Comment: i use a button with a call to this function for every order in history.tpl

Comment: Ok, could you edit your first message and add the tpl, I think the mistake comes from the way you call this function

Comment: in history.tpl I insert the folowing li option: <td class="history_detail">
            <a class="btn-default button" href="{Order::duplicateOrder({$order.id_order})}" title="{l s='Duplicare comanda'}">  
        <span>
         {l s='Duplicare comanda'}
                                    <i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i>
        </span>
       </a>
      </td>

Comment: so the concern comes from the: href = "{Order :: duplicateOrder ({$ order.id_order})}" the hit code is executed on load. It should rather call the link to the click in ajax. So the worry would not be present.

Comment: so, for an ajax call i need to rewrite this function in java? or exist already this functionality in prestashop?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution with javascript?

Comment: Ok, otherwise you create a php page at the root, in which you include the config / config.inc.php, which receives in parameter in the url the command to duplicate. In this page, you launch the call of the function, and then you make a redirection.

Answer (score 0):

in history.tpl I inserted the folowing li option after Reorder button; whenever I press the refresh (F5) the orders are multiplicated (2, 4, 8, 16 and so on)

{l s='Duplicate Order'}

the function was saved in classes\Order\Order.php

Comment: thanks for your comment, but could you provide an example call?